# Unable to execute script on linux box C#

Tags: c#, linux, ssh

I am using the following C# code to connect to a Linux box and execute a script that is placed there

```
public static void linux_connect()
    {

    KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod kauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(<username>);
    PasswordAuthenticationMethod pauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(<username>,<password>);

    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(<host ip>, 22, <username>, kauth, pauth);

    using (var ssh = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
    {
        ssh.Connect();
        string command = "tmp/Ftp.sh";
        var cmd = ssh.CreateCommand(command);
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.Result);
        var asynch = cmd.BeginExecute(delegate(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

        }, null);


        var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream);


        while (!asynch.IsCompleted)
        {
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                continue;
            Console.Write(result);
        }
        cmd.EndExecute(asynch);

    }

}
```

My Ftp.sh script is a s follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /apps/sample_folder

sudo -u (authorized_username) ftp (some_server)
```

The cd command executes successfully but when control reaches the sudo command, I should be prompted for a password on my console but unfortunately I am not. Could someone please tell me how to make this interactive so that I am prompted for a password on my application console and I am able to enter it and then copy file from  to the desired location

Comment: I don't know how your SSHClient works but my guess is that you are trying to read the output when the command completed. But the command didn't complete since it's expecting a password. You need to somehow send the password after the call to the command but before its execution ends. I don't know if your SSHClient class can notify you in such event. Read the manual.